# Can't Add Android Platform on Meteor

Tags: android, meteor

I prefer to use my existing Android Development Kit for my meteor project. From wiki page i found here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration, i should use the USE_GLOBAL_ADK as follow:

```
env USE_GLOBAL_ADK=t meteor add-platform android
```

but i got following message:

```
The Android platform is not installed; please run: meteor install-sdk android
```

I also have already setup the ADK to PATH var so android and adb comands could be run from terminal.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `env USE_GLOBAL_ADK=t meteor --verbose install-sdk android` first and you may need to download the latest APK with the latest build tools.  Ensure that the build tools is in your path.  That worked for me.